# Latest record and sum SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for solution for this problem.

Table:

[image]

i want this output (show latest tier based on maximum transaction id)

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Most people consider all caps in a title shouting.

Comment: How do you choose which tier to select for trans_id?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
select *, sum(select sum(t1.poin)
              from table t1
              where t1.member_id = t.member_id
             ) as poin,
          sum(select sum(t1.freq)
              from table t1
              where t1.member_id = t.member_id
             ) as freq
from table t
where trans_id = (select t1.trans_id
                  from table t1
                  where t1.member_id = t.member_id
                  order by t1.trans_id desc
                  fetch first 1 rows only
                 );
```

Most *DBMS* has support `fetch first 1 rows only` method.

If, you are working with SQL Server, then you can directly express it as :

```
select t.member_id, tt.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by member_id order by trans_id desc) as seq
      from table
     ) t cross apply (
            select sum(t1.poin) as poin, sum(t1.freq) as freq
            from table t1
            where t1.member_id = t.member_id
     ) tt
where t.seq = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help sir. It works well. 
Minor correction, first row, type: select t.member_id, t.tier, tt.* to get tier information.
Really appreciate it. :)